# Remove words at specific delimitation from string in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is my string which is loaded to select box from a text file

```
MML;SoldBagsReport;Merchant;APCS--T1;04/01/2016;
MML;SoldBagsReport;Client;MMSL--R10;04/12/2015;
```

But I want to load only

```
APCS--T1
MMSL--R10
```

from the above string. How to remove other words by Jquery or PHP?

Comment: will that word be after 3rd semicolon always or will its position change?

Comment: Yes, always at same position and `MML,SoldBagsReport,Merchant` and ending `date` in the string may change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a particular word from a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257050/how-do-i-get-a-particular-word-from-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your required string always come at third position in the string, following code should work.

What we have done is:

Split the string by `;`.

Get the third split string.

That is required.

```
function getRequiredString($str = '') {
  $temp = explode(';', $str);
  return isset($temp[3]) ? $temp[3] : '';
}
$str = 'MML;SoldBagsReport;Merchant;APCS--T1;04/01/2016';
$requiredStr = getRequiredString($str);
echo $requiredStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use PHP

```
$csv = "MML;SoldBagsReport;Merchant;APCS--T1;04/01/2016;";
$data = explode(";", $csv);
$desiredPart = $data[3];

// Or in one line
$part = explode(";", "MML;SoldBagsReport;Merchant;APCS--T1;04/01/2016;")[3]
```

or Javascript (no special need of jQuery)

```
csv = "MML;SoldBagsReport;Merchant;APCS--T1;04/01/2016;";
data = csv.split(";");
part = data[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "MML;SoldBagsReport;Merchant;APCS--T1;04/01/2016;";
$split = explode(";", $str);

echo $split[3];
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript here, no need to use jquery. Split string with semicolon as delimitor and take out 4th string, see below code

```
var str = MML;SoldBagsReport;Merchant;APCS--T1;04/01/2016;
var splitStr = str.split(";");
alert(splitStr[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

*How to remove other words by Jquery or PHP?*

well using <strike>jQuery</strike> javascript you can do this:

1. Get the array of your strings.
2. use a loop to takeout each string one at a time.
3. use `.match()` with a specific regular expression.
4. return the first index out of array from match.

```js
var arr = ["MML;SoldBagsReport;Merchant;APCS--T1;04/01/2016",
  "MML;SoldBagsReport;Client;MMSL--R10;04/12/2015"
]

var strs = arr.map(function(str){
  return str.match(/(\w)+(--)+(\w\d+)/g)[0];
});

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(strs);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```